# re-open already closed

Tags: android, sqlite

When I use the `getPesoCount()` like in the:

```
Log.v("SQL", String.valueOf(getPesoCount()));
```

I get aN error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: attemp to re-open an already-closed object:   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery(mSql = SELECT * FROM pesoTable)...

```
 public void addPeso(int peso, String date) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PESO, peso); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_DATE, date); // Contact Phone Number

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_PESO, null, values);
        Log.v("SQL", String.valueOf(getPesoCount()));
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }


    public int getPesoCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PESO;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
```

If I don't use  `getPesoCount()`, no error occurs.

Can someone help me?

Comment: remove this line `cursor.close();`

Comment: Thanks for te fast awnser :) i have used another method

Comment: I added a: int c = cursor.getCount(); before cursor.close() and then return c;

Comment: yes it is a good option `Convert` you cursor in other object model. and then make it close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
attempt to re-open an already-closed object:
```

Exception tells you a lot!

If you want to use the `cursor` further do not call `cursor.close();` call it when you are sure that you do not need it anymore.

Comment: His issue may have been with db.close(), not cursor.close()

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void addPeso(int peso, String date) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PESO, peso); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_DATE, date); // Contact Phone Number

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_PESO, null, values);
        Log.v("SQL", String.valueOf(getPesoCount(db)));
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }




    public int getPesoCount(db) {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PESO;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }
```